# Generating getter in Intellij for a groovy class without a return statement

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I have a groovy project in IntelliJ. I have a class level property and I am trying to generate a getter method using (Command + N) or (Ctrl + N) without the return statement.

```
class MyClass {
  final String myProperty

  // generate the below getter from intelliJ
  String getMyProperty() {
    myProperty
  }
}
```

I cannot use the @Immutable annotation from groovy as well because it is incompatible, because I have to declare an empty constructor because the POGO is being used as an entity object for Hibernate/JPA

Answer (score 2):

Getters and setters are not needed when you create a POGO class

> *"When writing your beans in Groovy, often called POGOs (Plain Old Groovy Objects), you don’t have to create the field and getter / setter yourself, but let the Groovy compiler do it for you."*
>
> Source: http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_getters_and_setters

So instead

```
class MyClass {
  String myProperty

  // generate the below getter from intelliJ
  String getMyProperty() {
    myProperty
  }
}
```

all you need is

```
class MyClass {
  String myProperty
}
```

What happens at the bytecode level is the field `myProperty` is compiled to a `private String myProperty` equivalent and public `getMyProperty` and `setMyProperty` methods are generated for you.

On the other hand, [return keyword is optional in Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_return_keyword_optional). The method that got generated by your IntelliJ IDEA is correct. In this case the last expression of the body method gets returned.

Comment: Yes good point. One thing I missed was my POGO is immutable thus there is a `final` statement in myProperty. I cannot use the @Immutable groovy annotation, because hibernate/jpa is not compatible because it requires an empty constructor if you declare final parameters.

Comment: If you property is declared `final`, Groovy will just generate a getter for you.